# Vue Js - Delete a TR grand-parent node from a table on click firing a method

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

I have a table that I want to be able to delete the specific grand-parent node of the element with the click event - in this case a button. I want it to traverse up to its TR and remove it from the DOM. As it stands, the code does nothing, no errors and no deleting occurs.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Script example:

```
data () {
         return {
            items: []
         }
      },
 methods: {
             deleteItem(event){
                let con = confirm('Are you sure?');
                if(con) {
                   let par = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
                   for( let i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
                      if(event) {
                         this.items.items.splice(i, 1);
                      }
                   }
                }
             },
    }
```

Table Example:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Item</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in items">
         <td><input type="text" v-model="item.q" required></td>
         <td><button v-on:click.prevent="deleteItem">X</button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you,

-S

Comment: Vue uses declarative DOM, you should avoid manipulating it manually. In this case you should just remove the item from `items` and let the re-render take care of deleting it.

Comment: @Matt Thanks Matt. But how can I just remove it? I've tried a bunch of ways I have seen on here and other forums, but it either removes and throws an error or just throws the error and does not remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from comments.. you can just delete the `item` and let the re-render remove the old DOM for you.

E.g. change your handler to pass the current item reference:

`v-on:click.prevent="deleteItem(item)"`

Then filter it out in your `deleteItem` method:

```
deleteItem(item) {
  this.items = this.items.filter(it => it !== item);
}
```

Full example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POGgWp

Comment: Matt this worked, can you explain what is actually making the deletion. Is it the filter function? Never used before.

Comment: Vue is like React if you are familiar with that. Basically, any time state (anything in `data` here) updates, Vue will re-render your template based on that new state. Vue then detects differences since the last render and makes the necessary changes to the DOM for you (this is called "consolidation"). The [Vue guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering) is a good starting place to read more

Comment: Ah, makes sense. So we are not really "deleting" just creating a new instance without the item we marked as "deleted" and rendering that instead - am I on the right track with this assumption? Thank again.

Comment: `item` is definitely gone in my example. The template is declaratively saying "hey, create a table row for each item." So when that `items` array is modified, this triggers Vue to run the template again with the new `items` array, and comes up 1 row short. Vue detects this and literally calls `removeChild` behind the scenes. Again, my example actually removes the `item` forever, but the same effect would happen if you moved it to a separate array. The key is `items` has to not have that `item` anymore.

Comment: Got it... Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Yes, we create a new instance of the template without the `item`. This is considered "virtual DOM". Vue compares the previous two virtual DOMs and then makes changes to the real DOM to bring it up to date

Comment: Gosh, I also misread further. Yes, `filter` removes `item`, because it returns a new `items` array of things that don't match the reference you pass it in. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) have more info on that function

Comment: Lol. No worries, I think I have a good idea how Vue behaves with these sort of situations now. In fact with your example above, I was able to refactor a few additional methods. Much appreciated Matt.